# Realm copyToRealmOrUpdate v/s insertOrUpdate

Tags: android, realm

Whats the difference in copyToRealmOrUpdate v/s insertOrUpdate in Realm while saving object. Which one should be considered to apply?

Comment: Read Doc [copyToRealmOrUpdate](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyToRealmOrUpdate-java.lang.Iterable-io.realm.ImportFlag...-) and [insertOrUpdate](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#insertOrUpdate-java.util.Collection-)

Comment: Just got run into an issue, with `copyToRealmOrUpdate`, it throws exception for created objects without primary key. `insertOrUpdate`, instead, can insert an object with no primary key into Realm!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`insertOrUpdate()` is a new method introduced in 1.1.0 that has none of the performance issues of `copyToRealmOrUpdate`.

The biggest visible difference is that `insertOrUpdate()` doesn't return the added objects, which allowed the team to optimize it much more heavily.